# Use SceneKit to render an CVOpenGLTextureRef

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl, scenekit

I am using `AVCaptureSession`, and outputting a `CVOpenGLTextureRef` at 60fps, which I need to display using SceneKit.

I'm fairly sure I should be using the `SCNProgramDelegate` method `bindValueForSymbol:` but can't quite figure out the mechanism to bind the texture ref. The examples I have seen use a `GLKTextureInfo` object, and bind its `name` property with the call to `glBindTexture()`.

What is the equivalent mechanism to do this with an `CVOpenGLTextureRef`?

Answer (score 2):

A relatively easy solution may be to use `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. You can set it directly as the contents of the diffuse material of the geometry you want to display the frames on, and you get the benefits of all the optimisation work that Apple have (probably) done for this. AVFoundation and SceneKit will handle all the details for you.

If you are doing work on the CPU to the incoming buffer, there's also the lower level `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` class, which lets you pass `CMSampleBufferRef` objects, which you can build from a `CVPixelBufferRef`. It's a bit more difficult to feed and care for, but not impossible.